# TailwindCSS Media Queries Not Working in Pug Template

Tags: tailwind-css, pug

I'm facing an issue with TailwindCSS media queries when using them in a Pug template. The media query styles aren't being applied as expected.

The rendered HTML is:

```
<div id="caracteristica">
    <img class="w-5 md:w-10" src="../../../../assets/images/caracteristicas/2.png">
    <h2>Blah</h2>
    <p>Blah blah blah...</p>
</div>
```

Here's my Pug code:

```
mixin caracteristica(image, title, description)
  #caracteristica(class="")
    img(class="w-5 md:w-10" src=image)
    h2= title
    p= description
```

And I'm invoking the mixin like:

```
+caracteristica("../../../../assets/images/caracteristicas/2.png", "blah...", "blah blah blah...")
```

Despite this, when I resize the browser to a medium-sized screen, the image width doesn't change to w-10 as specified in the class.

What I've tried:

Ensuring the TailwindCSS files are included.
Checked that the browser's viewport is being resized to the medium breakpoint.
Reviewed the order of classes (w-5 before md:w-10).
Inspected the element in DevTools to see if md:w-10 is being applied.
Any help would be appreciated. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: To be sure we're on the same page, with default configuration `md:` means **minimum** viewport width of `768px`, so ensure when you are resizing your browser, it is larger than `768px` in width. Consider checking that `content` file globs in your Tailwind configuration cover the pug template file.